# Croatian characters and python

Tags: python, string, file, utf-8

I have done a simple program which finds out if given string is found in file.

```
a=raw_input('write some string ')
f1=open("croatian.txt",'r')

def check():

    found = False 
    for line in f1:
        if ("%s"%a) in line:
        found=True
    print found


check()
```

I use a few charachters (č,ć,ž,đ,š) (characters in Croatian language) which are not recognized by code written above. For example, if I write string "čokolada", program says "False", althought word "čokolada" is found in file. How to solve this?

Comment: Why do you use the expression `("%s"%a)`? It's the same as `a`.

Comment: Because I have seen and learnt it somewhere in that fashion

Comment: @Zvone unlearn it. `if a in line:`  does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

It's probable that the text is using different encoding. If the file is UTF-8 encoded but you're running the program on Windows, it's almost certain. You should convert everything to Unicode and then do the check.

To convert the input string:

```
a = a.decode(sys.stdin.encoding)
```

To convert the file, you can use `codecs` to open the file or you can convert each line as it's read. Note that you only need *one* of these changes!

```
f1 = codecs.open("croatian.txt", 'r', 'utf-8')
```

or:

```
line = line.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Tried it but it did not help me. Still get "False" on words containting č,ć,ž,š,đ.

Comment: @ZvonePeran are you sure of the encoding of your file? Maybe it's not UTF8.

Comment: Yes, it is. I have checked it right now. Still did not get the solutin. Any more ideas?

Comment: @ZvonePeran try doing `print repr(a)` and see if there are any unexpected characters in the string.

Comment: I have done it and for word "čokolada" I got answer u'\u010dokolada'. Is that expected behavior?

Comment: @ZvonePeran yes that is exactly correct, the `\u010d` translates to the character `č`, see http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10d/index.htm. Now do the same for one of the lines of the file that have an accented character.

Comment: Now, the answer is "u'\xe8okolada". In a file it is written as "èokolada". Is that expected?

Comment: May I use method str.replace() to replace "\xe8" with "\u010d" and do so for every character(ćžšđ), or there is more simple way to do it?

Comment: @ZvonePeran I'm confused now. If the file wasn't UTF-8 then you would have gotten a `decode` error when you tried to read it, so the character must be corrupted in your file. I think doing the `replace` would be a straight forward solution, but it would be better to find out how the file became corrupted.

Comment: Probably I got it corrupted.

Comment: `\xe8` is cp1250-encoded for `č` and `cp1252`-encoded for `è`.  @Zvone I think your file is encoded in `cp1250` (Windows Central European encoding), not UTF-8, but you are reading it with `cp1252`.

Answer (score 0):

probably you are trying to open an unicode file (usually in UTF-8 encoding).
As any file can be read and decoded with ASCII, you have no exceptions here.

Use codecs to open such files:

```
import codecs
f1 = codecs.open("croatian.txt", "r", "utf-8")
```

Also you may refactor you function in more pythonic way:

```
print 'Found' if any(a in line for line in f1) else 'Not Found'
```

Comment: Same as above. It did not help me.